# 'Provided id of the wrong type', even though table id is set with auto_increment?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am creating an h2 table for unit testing, the table is created with this sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RULE_LIST
(
   RULE_LIST_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
   RULE_TYP_CDE varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   RULE_GROUP varchar(50),
   RULE_NM varchar(128),
);
```

I then attempt to insert a row with:

```
DELETE FROM RULE_LIST;
INSERT INTO RULE_LIST(
  RULE_TYP_CDE,
  RULE_GROUP,
  RULE_NM
)
VALUES (
  'testType',
  'testGroup',
  'testName'
);
```

But this results in the exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class [associated java entity]. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer`.
I don't know where or what is trying to insert an integer for the id, as I thought it would be generated with auto_increment and I did not include an integer in my insert statement. What's going on here?

Comment: Did you check if there is already a table with a Long field? `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`  doesnt do anything if there is already a table

Comment: care to tell people where the JPA API comes into this? and then update the question with the JPA code; nope the JPA API is not execution of your own SQL statements